# Row.T * Row dot product of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am searching for a faster and maybe more elegant way to compute the following:
I have a matrix A and I want to compute the row-wise dot product of A. Herby I want to compute A<sub>i</sub>.T * A<sub>i</sub>, whereby index i indicates the ith row of matrix A.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.arange(40).reshape(20,2)
sol=[np.dot(A[ii,:].reshape(1,2).T,A[ii,:].reshape(1,2)) for ii in range(20)]
```

This results in  a matrix of shape `np.shape(sol) #=(20,2,2)`
I already had a look at `np.einsum`, but could not make it work so far.
If there only exists a solution, where all 20 2x2 matrices are summed, this is also okay, since I want to sum it anyway in the end :)

Thanks

Comment: What's must be the shape of output from - `"all 20 2x2 matrices are summed"`?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguousness. With the sum I meant a sum over all 20 2x2 matrices, resulting in one 2x2 matrix. `sol=[np.sum(np.dot(A[ii,:].reshape(1,2).T,A[ii,:].reshape(1,2)) for ii in range(20))]`

Comment: Check out the edits in my post please. Also, that code in your comment : `sol=[np.sum(...` doesn't work. It would be nice of you to verify a code with the given sample before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `np.dot` -

```
A.T.dot(A)
```

Using `np.einsum` -

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->jk',A,A)
```

Sample run -

```
>>> A=np.arange(40).reshape(20,2)
>>> sol=[np.dot(A[ii,:].reshape(1,2).T,A[ii,:].reshape(1,2)) for ii in range(20)]
>>> sol = np.array(sol)
>>> sol.sum(0)
array([[ 9880, 10260],
       [10260, 10660]])
>>> A.T.dot(A)
array([[ 9880, 10260],
       [10260, 10660]])
>>> np.einsum('ij,ik->jk',A,A)
array([[ 9880, 10260],
       [10260, 10660]])
```

If the result must be a `20` element array, I think you need -

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->i',A,A)
```